# Time series forcasting with SVR

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, svm

I have a time series and I would like to use `xt` to predict `xt + 1`. I am using sklearn's Support vector regression, but I can not understand what I did wrong to have this shift in my predictions. Here is my code and the result (in the image).

```
bts_sup = timeseries_to_supervised(bts,1)
bts_sup = bts_sup.iloc[1:,:]   # delete the line because x0 don't have antecedant
train, test = split_data(bts_sup)

# sacling data
scaler_in = MinMaxScaler()  #  for inputs
scaler_out = MinMaxScaler()  # for outputs

X_train = scaler_in.fit_transform(train[:,0].reshape(-1,1))
y_train = scaler_out.fit_transform(train[:,1].reshape(-1,1))

X_test = scaler_in.transform(test[:,0].reshape(-1,1))
y_test = scaler_out.transform(test[:,1].reshape(-1,1))


param_grid = {"C": np.linspace(10**(-2),10**3,100),
             'gamma': np.linspace(0.0001,1,20)}

mod = SVR(epsilon = 0.1,kernel='rbf')
model = GridSearchCV(estimator = mod, param_grid = param_grid,
                                   scoring = "neg_mean_squared_error",verbose = 0)

best_model = model.fit(X_train, y_train.ravel())

#prediction
predicted_tr = model.predict(X_train)
predicted_te = model.predict(X_test)

# inverse_transform because prediction is done on scaled inputs
predicted_tr = scaler_out.inverse_transform(predicted_tr.reshape(-1,1))
predicted_te = scaler_out.inverse_transform(predicted_te.reshape(-1,1))

#plot
forcast = np.concatenate((predicted_tr,predicted_te))
real = np.concatenate((train[:,1],test[:,1]))
plt.plot(real, color = 'blue', label = 'Real Erlangs')
plt.plot(forcast,"--", linewidth=2,color = 'red', label = 'Predicted Erlangs')
plt.title('Erlangs Prediction--'+data_set.columns[choice])
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Erlangs')
plt.legend()
plt.show()


#error
print("MSE: ", mse(real,forcast), " R2: ", r2_score(real,forcast))
print(best_model.best_params_)
```

## train

> [[ 9.26 11.01]  [11.01 22.72]  [22.72 20.75]  [20.75 11.54]  [11.54
>   11.85]  [11.85 18.17]  [18.17 16.05]  [16.05 17.98]  [17.98 14.85]  [14.85 12.62]  [12.62 16.95]  [16.95 16.81]  [16.81 16.23]  [16.23
>   21.81]  [21.81 22.47]  [22.47 20.37]  [20.37 16.68]  [16.68 17.07]  [17.07 20.48]  [20.48 21.99]  [21.99 25.54]  [25.54 21.1 ]  [21.1 
>   16.91]  [16.91 24.23]  [24.23 27.37]  [27.37 30.55]  [30.55 28.47]  [28.47 26.74]  [26.74 40.37]  [40.37 36.55]  [36.55 39.65]  [39.65
>   45.58]  [45.58 48.91]  [48.91 37.82]  [37.82 39.7 ]  [39.7  36.09]  [36.09 25.33]  [25.33 23.64]  [23.64 18.33]  [18.33 21.59]  [21.59
>   22.4 ]  [22.4  15.89]  [15.89 18.94]  [18.94 21.78]  [21.78 19.38]  [19.38 17.81]  [17.81 21.33]  [21.33 22.61]  [22.61 27.11]  [27.11
>   26.48]  [26.48 19.87]  [19.87 18.57]  [18.57 14.03]  [14.03 18.82]  [18.82 22.46]  [22.46 22.33]  [22.33 21.58]  [21.58 22.66]  [22.66
>   19.51]  [19.51 21.54]  [21.54 20.58]  [20.58 20.48]]

## test

> [[20.48 25.78]  [25.78 21.89]  [21.89 19.61]  [19.61 22.95]  [22.95
>   21.67]  [21.67 26.03]  [26.03 21.96]  [21.96 21.81]  [21.81 21.91]  [21.91 21.82]  [21.82 19.6 ]  [19.6  24.61]  [24.61 30.97]  [30.97
>   18.29]  [18.29 19.84]  [19.84 20.81]  [20.81 29.17]  [29.17 24.01]  [24.01 21.3 ]  [21.3  25.08]  [25.08 27.18]  [27.18 26.59]  [26.59
>   25.99]  [25.99 28.74]  [28.74 25.32]  [25.32 27.56]  [27.56 28.69]]

[image: Result graph]

Comment: can you add sample data in timeseries_to_supervised in this variable?

Comment: Kindly dont paste the image. Put that as part of the question itself (copy, paste the data).

Comment: ok. thank  you. I just add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my observation, the model is prediction a value close to previous time period, which had been given as input data. Small variance can be observed when the `x_t` is low, model predicts `x_t+1` as slightly higher and inverse case when x_t is a high value.

This seems to be the best guess from the model, with only one lag feature.

Ways to improve could be add additional features 5-10 lags and let model learning pattern which is running through.

For more complex model, you can try RNN for forecasting, if SVM doesnot work.